# SAP hybris Spring set SameSite cookie

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud, setcookie

I'm using SAP hybris 6.7 and trying to set the SameSite flag.

Actually there is just an easy property for it: https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/6.7.0.0/en-US/bde41b6a42c541a08eb2a3b1993fb097.html?q=samesite

Unfortunately it still does not work.
`Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=616707B8B913B126FBA507D4DC6130B2; Expires=Tue, 15-Sep-2020 10:20:29 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly` - there is no "SameSite=None".

Do I need to configure something else too? Or do I have to create a new CookieFilter?

Comment: [katsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1268553) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66857366) saying "I checked this article work for me, my version is 18.11.latest patch. [https://clutcher.github.io/post/hybris/same_site_login_issue/](https://clutcher.github.io/post/hybris/same_site_login_issue/)"

Answer (score 1):

There is a related question in SAP answers, but it's for Hybris 6.2: https://answers.sap.com/questions/13173060/samesite-cookie-attribute.html

Considering that you are using an old and unsupported version that will no longer get updates, it's probably better to do what was suggested:

- Extend ServerCookie, and create an overloaded appendCookieValue method which contains sameSite attribute
- Extend CookieGenerator to use the new appendCookieValue method

Answer (score 0):

I checked SAP hybris code (6.7,1905 and 2005 bundles). According to that only 2005 supports it. 6.7 and 1905 versions do not have anything related to samesite cookie flag.

I tried `cookies.SameSite.enabled` flag with hybris 6.7 and 1905 and as expected, it did not work.  It works only with version 2005.

SAP has added support for reading this flag in 2005 version. Documentation from SAP (6.7) is misleading.